# How to use sortby in foreach loop in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to sort the data according to user_id, but i want it to be done using a foreach loop, How can i use a use sortby for that

```
$wms = WmsProduct::where('id',$product_id)->select('id','user_id')->get();
foreach($wms as $index => $list){
  //      
}
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Could you give us a sample of the output and a sample of the order you're trying to get it into?

Answer (score 0):

You can add:

```
WmsProduct::where('id',$product_id)->select('id','user_id')->orderBy('user_id', 'desc')
```

Or:

```
foreach($wms->sortBy('user_id') as $index => $list)
```

Or:

```
foreach($wms->sortByDesc('user_id') as $index => $list)
```

Though you have to be careful when using sort in a foreach, if no records are found, I think it throws an error, so check for that.